# Adding Multiple Lines to Text Box in PPT 2010 in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to reference one text box (named WarningText1) and output multiple lines of text depending on what the user selects in the GUI. This is what I am trying:

```
Private Sub WarningInfo()
    Call Dictionary.WarningInfo 
    Call Dictionary.WindInfo 

    'Sets the font for the warning information text.
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font 
        .Size = 24 
        .Name = "Aharoni" 
        .Shadow.Visible = True 
    End With 

    ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(ComboBox2), CStr(ComboBox3), CStr(ComboBox4), CStr(ComboBox5), CStr(ComboBox6)) 

    For Each Ky In ComboBoxList 
        On Error Resume Next 
         'If nothing is selected in all dropdowns, do nothing and exit this sub.
        If ComboBox2 = "" And ComboBox3 = "" And ComboBox4 = "" And ComboBox5 = "" And ComboBox6 = "" Then 
            Exit Sub 
             'Otherwise, if even one dropdown has a selection, insert selected text.
        Else 
            ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = dict2.Item(Ky)(0) & dict3.Item(Ky)(0) 
        End If 
    Next 

    Set dict2 = Nothing 

End Sub
```

When I run that line of code using EITHER the dict2 or dict3 line, it works great. But it doesn't seem to be able to add them together this way.

When run, I get the error: "Type mismatch".

Also, When I put `dict2.Item(Ky)(0) & dict2.Item(Ky)(0)` (the same thing twice), it works.

I assume there is a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it anywhere online. Appreciate any help!

*****EDIT*****

I added code to help debug. This was added right before the line that is not working:

```
Debug.Print dict2.Item(Ky)(0)
Debug.Print dict3.Item(Ky)(0)
```

Both values printed out exactly what they were supposed to. It just won't add them both to the same text box.

****EDIT 2****

As you can see in the code above, I am calling my dictionaries into this Sub. Here is the code of what my dictionaries look like:

```
Option Private Module 'This is necessary so that these modules do not show up in the PPT Macro window.
Public dict, dict2, dict3 As Object, Key, val 'Makes the dictionaries public so they can be accessed by other Modules.

Sub WarningInfo()

'This is the dictionary for the maximum expected hail size.

Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Key = "No Hail": val = Array("No hail expected")
dict2.Add Key, val
Key = "0.25""": val = Array("Hail: Up to 0.25""")
dict2.Add Key, val
Key = "0.50""": val = Array("Hail: Up to 0.50""")
dict2.Add Key, val

End Sub

Sub WindInfo()

'This is the dictionary for the maximum expected wind speed.

Set dict3 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Key = "35 mph": val = Array("Wind: Up to 35 mph")
dict3.Add Key, val
Key = "40 mph": val = Array("Wind: Up to 40 mph")
dict3.Add Key, val
Key = "45 mph": val = Array("Wind: Up to 45 mph")
dict3.Add Key, val

End Sub
```

The dictionary is where I set my variables, dict2 and dict3.

Thanks,

Cory

Comment: If your question is how to put the two entries into two lines, insert a vbCrLf between them: `dict2.Item(Ky)(0) & vbCrLf & dict3.Item(Ky)(0)`

Comment: Andre, I don't need that, but thanks. When I run it as is shown in the code above, I get a Type Mismatch Error. Not sure why.

Comment: That's a rather relevant piece of information, isn't it? Please add it to the question.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I only just noticed that since I commented out the "On Error Resume Next". Also, When I put `dict2.Item(Ky)(0) & dict2.Item(Ky)(0)` (the same thing twice), it works.

Comment: Do you have the code with the variables declared? As an aside, it's good programming practice in VBA to add the following first line to your code, above all procedures:

   Option Explicit

and then declare all variables. This will save you a LOT of debugging time.

So I can't see what data type dict2.Item(Ky)(0) is supposed to be returning. I also can't see where you are setting a reference to the dict2 object (or dict3) even though you are clearing it in the last line.

Comment: Following up on @JamieG's suggestions, put a breakpoint at the problem line, then in the immediate window type:  ? Typename(dict3.Item(Ky)(0))  and do the same for dict2.  TypeName will tell you what PowerPoint thinks is stored in your dictionary;  if it thinks it's something different from what you think, it wins.

Comment: Jamie and Steve, thanks for the suggestions! I have updated my question to show you what the dictionary looks like. I declare my variables in the Dictionary and then that dictionary is called into the Sub. Is this now how that should be done? Thanks!

Comment: Also, Steve, when I run that, it says "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not set". But when I run the script using just dict2.Item(Ky)(0) OR dict3.Item(Ky)(0) [i.e. not both], it works as expected (outputs the variable the user selected to the text box). It can't know which variable (Ky) is supposed to be unless they are first selected in the drop down within the GUI. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So the dictionary object is being set with type string for the key and an array for the value and dict3.Item(Ky)(0) is trying to return a string based on the string key 'Ky' and the first item of the value array. So I think what's happening is that you're passing the same key name to the two dictionary objects and hence it's only finding the Ky item in only one of the dictionaries. So do you not need to get the dict second item based on the index of the first?